# How do you write "forces" in set theory, in Latex?

Tags: logic

I just learned forcing in my Set theory class. I am wondering how do we write "forces" denoted by a symbol that looks somewhat similar to, but different, o`$\models$o`.

Comment: Wikipedia uses `\Vdash`, I assume that's standard?

Comment: See also [How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-letter-from-a-math-alphabet-or-other-chara/21#21)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the symbol you're looking for is `\Vdash` available by loading the `amssymb` package.

Also, you want to put your whole math expression inside the `$`…`$`, not just the special symbol, so `$o \Vdash o$`.

Finally, when you're trying to find a symbol, the [Detexify](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/) site (there's also an off-line tool) is handy for being able to draw a symbol and see what TeX commands will generate something similar.